# Can't curl because of invalid certificate

Tags: curl, https, request, certificate

Hei,

I'm trying to get the body of this page: https://www.dataprev.gov.br/FapWeb/pages/login.xhtml with curl, but isn't working, nothing happens... the terminal just freezes.

I believe the problem is because the page is using an invalid certificate.

Command:

```
curl -X GET https://www.dataprev.gov.br/FapWeb/pages/login.xhtml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page in question is currently down.

However, to allow cURL to make requests to pages with invalid certificates, add the `--insecure` or `-k` flag to the command:

```
curl -X --insecure GET https://www.dataprev.gov.br/FapWeb/pages/login.xhtml
```